# SImple Soap needed

Tags: xml, soap

I admit, I don't "get it" when it comes to soap.  I've got a code snipet I'm told will do what I need it to for the company we're working with.  Trouble is, I need more than a 'snipet'  I have zero knowledge when it comes to SOAP. I can do some C, java script, java, and X. I don't even know what to name the file that this goes in.  The company that sent it isn't being helpful.  I suspect they don't know either and this came from the guy they contracted in another country. For the experts this is probably easy but what I need is a from the ground up, what do I do with this. Obviously the names of fields were changed but it's pretty much exactly what I got.  It's going to be run on Linux.  I shortened the soap 'envelope' so it would fit on the page but supposedly the actual one is fine.

```
 POST /integration.asmx HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.thebigsite.com
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length
 SOAPAction: "http://www.thebigsite.com"

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="https://www.bigsite.com/">
      <service>1234567</service>
     <service2>89012345</service2>
     <service3>678901234567</service3>
     <service4>A1234567</service4>
     <firstName>Joe</firstName>
     <lastName>Shmo</lastName>
     <sumNumber>98989887</sumNumber>
     <anotherNumber>9999974747</anotherNumber>
     <yetanother>A1234567</yetanother>
     <emailAddress>someone@yahoo.com</emailAddress>
    </CreateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>


 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope >
     <soap:Body>
       <CreateRequest Response xmlns="https://www.thebigsite.com/">
        <CreateRequest Result>  result         </CreateRequest Result>
       </CreateRequest Response>
     </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

What they've given you here is a http request, and a http response.  You could then use a tool like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) to take the raw request and practice sending a few calls, and observing the response.

Then the next step would be to get it working on Linux.  Now you could use a tool like CURL to send the raw request, but I would recommend using a programming language that has a built in SOAP client, so you don't have to worry about parsing XML.  Take a look at PHP, Perl, or Python.

Comment: installed SoapUI.  Seems like something I'll need.   I hate to say it but, now what.  I read through some of the info and even tried importing the actual request and response but it came back with an error. I'm thinking, what should the file be called? I called it request.asp  Wrong type?   Should both parts be in the same file (it is) or separate.  I suspect there are more parts missing that I should have in place that would make these gears start turning.  If this is supposed to be in an html page, ok I can do that but is it a header item or can it be placed in between some tags elsewhere

Comment: I figured out how to pass the request via either get or post methods which turns out isn't much different than a run of the mill C written cgi.  Question is,  I'd like to capture the answer in a page without it opening a new one and simply displaying the response.  Any tips, anyone?

Comment: Were you provided a WSDL location?  I can show you how it's done in PHP.